# ScrollSpy Not Highlightling Last Section

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I have been using a template from startbootstrap.com called "creative" as shown [here](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/).

Because the last section is too short, it is never highlighted by scrollspy when it reaches the bottom of the page. However, as you can see in bootstrap documentation [examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/), this is accounted for. The last section is highlighted when the scroll reaches the bottom of the page regardless of the height of the last section. I have been looking around for a solution, but I have not found any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting it as answer But I can't send any image in comment it is working as you wanted..[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that's really strange. I'm not sure why the preview is not working properly on my computer.